# Error in getting results

Tags: python

**1-st Attempt**
Let's say a would like to see the chi_squared coefficient between two variables. I have implemented it such manner:

```
import scipy
X=data['V288'].values
Y = data['V780'].values
table = pd.crosstab(X,Y)

from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
chi2,p , dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table.values)
print  % (chi2, p)
```

After, i get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'tuple'
```

**2-nd attempt** 
But, when i print this way, i don't get error:

```
print   (chi2, p)
```

Output:

```
696.522768537 0.882613269189
```

I would like to understand, how to get results the way I've described in "1-st" attempt. And how can i interpret the results i already have.
Thank you!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Pandas, nor with SciPy...

Comment: instead of `print  % (chi2, p)` you have to write `print  "%s %s" % (chi2, p)` you are just facing problem with [string formatting](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting)